# iOS App URL percent encoding and decoding bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

In the iOS Stack Exchange app, I applied link formatting to a phase in a question using the following URL.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Attribute_Keys

The app then percent encoded the hash sign (#) to %23. When [tapping the link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Attribute_Keys) to open up the Stack Exchange app's in-app browser, I received a 404 error.

**Shouldn't the in-app browser percent decode URLs?**

I have also submitted feedback to Apple to asking for their servers to percent decode URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

The Markdown editor in the iOS app is a port of PageDown's Markdown.Editor.js to Objective-C.  When a URL is added, PageDown does some sanitization of the URL to add percent encoding, resulting in characters being passed to [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).  What's notable about this function is it preserves reserved characters, unescaped characters, and a third category "score" consisting of just #.

The similar method in Objective-C, `-[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]`, appears to preserve reserved characters and unescaped characters, but not #.  This is what caused the problem.  The fact that it doesn't document what characters are transformed is probably why it is deprecated in iOS9.

I went ahead and [switched](https://github.com/bnickel/SEMarkdownEditor/commit/65a3fc71e25e59782b10b7a103e65346e93269ee) to this monster:

```
return (__bridge_transfer id)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL,
    (__bridge CFStringRef)match,
    CFSTR(";,/?:@&=+$-_.!~*'()#"),
    NULL,
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Though it looks like that's also being deprecated in favor of the slightly more concise:

```
return [match stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:
    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";,/?:@&=+$-_.!~*'()#"]];
```

That said, I don't know this new method well enough to trust it so we'll deal with that later.

*As a side note*, the browser is doing what it should.  When it encounters the %23 it doesn't consider it a hash but as part of the path, so it thinks there's a folder named `index.html%23`.

Comment: The CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes method is deprecated in 9.0.

Adopted quemeful answer from How to encode a URL in Swift:

return [match stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];